# How to add new row to DataGridView binded to List<MyTableClass>

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have a WCF service that queries data from generated entity data model edmx and returns List. Then I bind the list to BindingSource and add it as DataSource for DataGridView. But on app execution when I try to add a new row to the DataGridView I get the exception: "System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid"
I added bindingSource.AllowNew = true but still is missing something. 
Could you tell me what I am doing wrong or missing to do?

All I want to do is to have updatable DataGridView using WCF services.

EDIT:

Service method:

```
public List<Cities> GetCities()
{
    try
    {
        CasinoEntities db = new CasinoEntities();
        List<Cities> lsCities = (from e in db.Cities select e).ToList<Cities>();
        return lsCities;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return null;
}
```

There is how get the list and bind it:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Service1Client dataServiceClient = new Service1Client();
    List<Cities> citiesList = dataServiceClient.GetCities().ToList();

    this.citiesBindingSource.AllowNew = true;
    this.citiesBindingSource.DataSource = citiesList;
    this.dgvData.DataSource = this.citiesBindingSource;
}
```

There is a generated Cities class from my entity model:

```
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Cities : EntityObject
{
    public static Cities CreateCities(global::System.Int32 id, global::System.String name, global::System.Int32 countryId, global::System.Byte[] timestamp)
    {
        Cities cities = new Cities();
        cities.Id = id;
        cities.Name = name;
        cities.CountryId = countryId;
        cities.Timestamp = timestamp;
        return cities;
    }

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                OnIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _Id;
    partial void OnIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Name;
    partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 CountryId
    {
        get
        {
            return _CountryId;
        }
        set
        {
            OnCountryIdChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("CountryId");
            _CountryId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("CountryId");
            OnCountryIdChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _CountryId;
    partial void OnCountryIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnCountryIdChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Byte[] Timestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return StructuralObject.GetValidValue(_Timestamp);
        }
        set
        {
            OnTimestampChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Timestamp");
            _Timestamp = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Timestamp");
            OnTimestampChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Byte[] _Timestamp;
    partial void OnTimestampChanging(global::System.Byte[] value);
    partial void OnTimestampChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to add a new record the `bindingSource` will try to create an instance of
`Cities`, so my guess is you have a combobox column on `countryId` property which takes 0 on create new instance of `Cities`, so let say you initialize the `comboCol` with `CountryList`, the solution is :

```
CountryList.Insert(0,new CountryClass() {CountryId = 0, CountryName = "<Select country>"});
```